# Javascript validar data anterior a hoje

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando validar um campo data do id 'txtDat', da seguinte forma:

Quero que, se a pessoa informar uma data anterior a hoje, mostre um `alert("Por favor, insira uma data futura.")`, e se informar uma data maior que 30 dias, mostre o `alert("Por favor, insira uma data menor que 30 dias.")` também, se não, ele segue.

Como base eu tenho esse código que consegui aqui no stack overflow para validar maior e menores de 65 anos

```
var data_ano = cad.txtDat.value;
var separa = ~data_ano.indexOf("/") ? "/" : "-";
var data_array = Number(data_ano.split(separa).filter(function(e){
   return e.length == 4;
}));

var este_ano = (new Date()).getFullYear();

if(data_array > este_ano-18 || data_array < este_ano-65){
   alert("É preciso ter 18 anos e menos de 65 anos.");
   return;
}
```

Eu tentei ao invés de `getfullyear` o `getday`, tentei várias outras coisas mas não consegui fazer.

Comment: https://momentjs.com - Talvez isso te ajude MUITO!

Comment: E se a data for igual a hoje?

Comment: Lembrando que fazer isso por JavaScript pode facilmente ser burlado. Basta o Usuário alterar a data do sistema.

Comment: @dvd faço por php então?

Comment: @dvd se a data for a de hoje tudo bem

Comment: Vc pode fazer pelos dois. No PHP é para validar de verdade.

Comment: então vou validar pelo php mesmo

Comment: @dvd mas teria como vc fazer essa função só pra eu ver como ficaria? caso eu fosse usar de urgencia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode verificar se a data informada é antes da data atual ou maior do que 30 dias da data atual:

```js
function validadata(d){
   var data = d.value; // pega o valor do input
   data = data.replace(/\//g, "-"); // substitui eventuais barras (ex. IE) "/" por hífen "-"
   var data_array = data.split("-"); // quebra a data em array
   var dia = data_array[2];
   var mes = data_array[1];
   var ano = data_array[0];

   // para o IE onde será inserido no formato dd/MM/yyyy
   if(data_array[0].length != 4){
      dia = data_array[0];
      mes = data_array[1];
      ano = data_array[2];
   }

   var hoje = new Date();
   var d1 = hoje.getDate();
   var m1 = hoje.getMonth()+1;
   var a1 = hoje.getFullYear();

   var d1 = new Date(a1, m1, d1);
   var d2 = new Date(ano, mes, dia);

   var diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
   diff = diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
   
   if(diff < 0){
      console.log("Data não pode ser anterior ao dia de hoje!");
   }else if(diff > 30){
      console.log("Data não pode ser mais do que 30 dias pra frente!");
   }else{
      console.log("Data válida!");
   }
   
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="txtDat" onchange="validadata(this)">
```

Comment: obrigado cara, não sei o que seria do meu TCC sem você, você é o cara! Semana que vem já irei apresentá-lo.